# Count of subsets of size r disjoint with a subset of size r

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

I apologize if I do not use 100% correct terminology:

Imagine I have a set $S$ with $n$ elements. S = {1,2,3,4,5}. If we want to calculate how many subsets of $S$ there are of size 2, then we must take $n$ choose 2. In this case we have the following 10 combinations:

{1,2},{1,3},{1,4},{1,5},{2,3},{2,4},{2,5},{3,4},{3,5},{4,5}

Now choosing one of these combinations, I would like to calculate how many other subsets are disjoint with it.

For example: Choose subset {1,2}. It is disjoint with 3 subsets: {3,4},{3,5},{4,5}

Is there a formula based on $n$ and size of the subset $r$ (in this example $r=2$) where I can calculate this number of disjoint subsets (in this example=3)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Take out the $r$ objects from the $n$ and you get $\binom{n-r}{r}.$ That if you care about the size of the disjoint set to be also $r$. If you want any size set it would be $2^{n-r}$.